# Route 53 API for Domain pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, price

I am using Route 53 Java Sdk to register a domain name. I am creating a view like AWS console to register a domain name through Route 53.

Is there any API available to get pricing based on TLDs? I want to display all the TLDs with their price same like AWS console as below.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is not. But the [pricing](https://d32ze2gidvkk54.cloudfront.net/Amazon_Route_53_Domain_Registration_Pricing_20140731.pdf) for all TLDs is available and linked at the bottom of the [Route53 product page](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/).

Answer (score 0):

From the [moment](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/about-aws/whats-new/2021/12/amazon-route-53-updates-api-actions/) list domain prices functionality is available through API. Description can be found in AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_domains_ListPrices.html